# $L^p$ $L^q$ $L^{\infty}$ inclusion + Folland

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Proposition 6.10 in Folland's Analysis book states:

> If $0 < p < q < r \leq \infty$, then $L^p \cap L^r \subset L^q$ and
>   $\|f\|_q \leq \|f\|_p^\lambda\|f\|_r^{1 - \lambda}$, where $\lambda
> \in (0,1)$ is defined by $$\lambda = \frac{\frac{1}{q} -
> \frac{1}{r}}{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{r}}.$$

For now, I am only interested in the case where $r = \infty$.  In the proof he says:

> If $r = \infty$, we have $|f|^q \leq \|f\|_\infty^{q - p}|f|^p$ ...

My problem is not how we use this inequality to get to our conclusion but rather where this inequality comes from in the first place.  He states this inequality as if it's an obvious fact, but apparently it isn't obvious to me.  Could someone explain where the inequality $|f|^q \leq \|f\|_\infty^{q - p}|f|^p$ comes from?

Comment: It is simply using the fact that $|f| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ almost everywhere. So $|f|^q = |f|^{q-p}|f|^p \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^{q-p}|f|^p$ since $q-p > 0$

Comment: Thanks, that really helps!